# Share service variable between controllers

Tags: ember.js

I have a variable in a service that I want two share between two controllers.
As I know, Ember services are singleton.

I created a service file: `app/services/data-manipulation.js`:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  init() {
     console.log('initService');
  },
  shouldManipulate: false
});
```

In first controller that is called one screen before the second controller:

```
dataManipulation: Ember.inject.service(),
init() {
   this.updateManipulate();
},
updateManipulate: function() {
   this.set("dataManipulation.shouldManipulate", true);
   var currentValue = this.get("dataManipulation.shouldManipulate");
   console.log(currentValue); // log true as expected
}
```

In second controller:

```
dataManipulation: Ember.inject.service(),
init() {
  // it inits the service again so 'initService' is logged again.
  var currentValue = this.get("dataManipulation.shouldManipulate");
  console.log(currentValue); // log undefined
}
```

What is the problem and how can I make it works?

Comment: What version of Ember are you using? Could you make an https://ember-twiddle.com demonstrating your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if the is any guarantee about the timing of `init` hooks of different controllers. What you are trying seems to be fragile to me. Still confused that it's not either `true` or `false` but `undefined`. A reproduction would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi, my version is 2.14. I will try to create twiddle and update it here. thank you!

Comment: It works on fiddle so I can't reproduce it :/
In the fiddle: It enters the service init only once.

Can you please think about what can cause it? I am trying to share this service variable between login page to another page. I've created this service so no-one changes it.

Maybe I need to declare this service globally?
I'm new developer in Ember.

Comment: Maybe there is a auto-refresh that causes it?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are on 2.14? Can you try in newer versions? Maybe it is an Ember bug that has been fixed.

Comment: Also, you should be using `setupController` in the Route, and not `init` in the Controller. Like mentioned above, `init` for controllers is not called when you think it is.